# Установка php 7 в Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, php7

Привет всем, не могу поставить на Ubuntu 14.04 версию PHP 7, нашёл инструкцию, но половина из тех команд не работает, например,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Может кто дать инструкцию? Спасибо.

Comment: Сообщите пожалуйста версию Ubuntu

Comment: версия убунту, а также ссылку на инструкцию которой пользовались и выдавало ли какие ошибки ,когда пытались юзать эти инструкции?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 :)))

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас чистый Ubuntu, то:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Если установлен PHP (например php5), то:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge php5-common -y
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove -y
```

---

Для версий: **Ubuntu 14.04 / 15.10**

 Начиная с **Ubuntu 16.04** - **PHP7** установлен по дефолту...

Comment: http://prntscr.com/avzdiz

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Теперь все ясно. Должно работать.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/avzsa7

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/149649

Comment: Со вчера у меня не работает такое, пишет
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'

После добавления репозитория есть возможность установить только php5. А при установке php7.0 или php5.6 пишет - что нет таких пакетов.